# How to refer special Hibernate property "class" in QueryDSL?

Tags: querydsl

Hibernate has a special "class" property. How to refer it in QueryDSL?

What I generally need is to group results by the entity type. [It is possible to do it in HQL.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3118623/289827)

Comment: I've found a workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3005654/289827

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the Hibernate `class` property, but the JPA `type` expression instead, via `JPAExpressions.type(entity)`.

Comment: it doesn't work with grouping in QueryDSL: `Unsupported expression unknown operation with operator com.mysema.query.jpa.JPQLOps#TYPE and args [sourceTable]`

Comment: Which Querydsl version do you use? And could you provide the full stacktrace?